# ActiveX Control created in .NET when hosted in IE doesn't recieve keyboard events

Tags: c#, .net, activex

I've been writing an ActiveX plugin for IE using .NET. While I've happily got it to deploy, install and what not, I'm finding that IE isn't passing keyboard events to it.

Is there a way to get IE to pass along keyboard events to it?

This problem has been seen to happen on IE7 and IE8, haven't tested other versions of IE though, mainly because I'm using IE8 and the customer will be using IE7.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
In this case the particular keys I'm interested in are the `delete` key and the `end` key

Comment: Any reason for the down votes?

Comment: What are the keyboard events in which you are interested?  I know certain keys will need special handling and it could be the difference between your problem being with those keys or generally ALL keys.

Comment: +1 Down voters should leave a comment (in my humble opinion)

Comment: Do you have any sample code, it would be easier to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with how the browser loads and exposes the object.

As a security measure, some objects will not be activated, until clicked on, and then receive keyboard input.

I actually found a solution Using JavaScript, to pass the characters to the ActiveX Object, so that you do not have to click on it first, to activate it.

I used it for a bar code scanning solution, as there was no keyboard or mouse attached to the device.

Silver light out of browser mode, made the keyboard input available straight away, and became a better solution. Not sure if the latest version still allows it.